# iterate through radio button group and display error

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 radio groups used in my code. In that 2 of them are required radio groups. On submit of the form, I need to check if the required radio groups are checked or not. If not checked I need to add an error message to the next div of that. But it is not working for me. Can some body help me?
Below is one radio group. So I am trying to iterate through the radio buttons and check if its not checked, adding error message. But it doesn't seem to be working. The "please select one" text appears for both the radio buttons. I need it only in one place below the second radio button.

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){
 $(this).next('div.error').remove();
var name = $(this).attr("name");
if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0){
    $(this).after('<div class="error">Please select one</div>');
    returnValue = false;
}
else{
    $(this).next('div.error').remove();
    returnValue = true;
}
```

});

HTML

```
 <input name="radio1" id="one" value="first" type="radio" class = "check"/>
 <input name="radio1" id="two" value="second" type="radio" class="check"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var requiredgroups = ['name1', 'name2'], returnValue = true;

$.each(requiredgroups, function(id, name){
    var $radios = $('input[name="' + name + '"]:radio');
    $radios.last().next('div.error').remove();

    if(!$radios.filter(':checked').length){
        $radios.last().after('<div class="error">Please select one</div>');
        returnValue = false;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hp5t6/)

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for the reply..The radio buttons in the radio group  are placed vertically. So for me, the error message is placed between the two. I want the error message to be placed below the second radio button. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1049057 you will have to edit the fiddle to replicate your case

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following implementation.
This implementation uses a group div where you can add a data-validation attribute to.
The javascript then uses this data-validation attribute to know which groups it must validate. I think this is a better implementation because it's very easy to reuse on other pages/websites/applications.

HTML:

```
<div class="group" data-validation="required">
<label><input name="radio1" value="first" type="radio" class = "check"/> First</label><br />
<label><input name="radio1" value="second" type="radio" class = "check"/>Second</label></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Bind validate function
$('button').on('click', validate);


function validate() {
    $('.error').remove();
    $.each($('.group[data-validation=required]'), function (idx, group) {
        var current = $(group).find('[type=radio]:checked').val()
        if( current === undefined ) {
            $(group).after('<div class="error">Please select one</div>');
        }
    });
}});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBBNa/)

Comment: Hi Wim..Just a query..what is data-validation in the html u have included? is it part of jquery validate plugin? Currently in my code I am not using jquery validate plugin..Also in all my radio buttons I have a class="required" already included. Will this create any issue with data-validation=required?